# Are Promises A+ promises required to execute side effects AFTER `.then` is called?

Tags: javascript, promise

I got tripped up by how the [Knex API for building a schema](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-createTable) doesn't actually create a table until you call `.then`.

For example, this code won't actually affect the database:

```
knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
  table.string('name')
})
```

But this code will:

```
knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
  table.string('name')
}).then(console.log.bind(console))
```

Is this behavior (not doing anything until `.then` is called):

a) required by the [Promises A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/)

b) prohibited by the [Promises A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/)

c) unspecified

?

I read the spec, and it seems like the behavior is unspecified, but I'm not sure. This seems too important to be unspecified.

#### Update

see @Vohuman's answer: The `then` method on the Knex schema builder first performs a side effect, then returns a promise. So even if the answer to my question is *(b)* Knex wouldn't be in violation of the spec. Though the choice of `then` as a method name is very misleading in this case.

Comment: The A+ spec leaves it unspecified, but such objects are known as *lazy promises*. There was some discussion whether the assimilation algorithm is allowed to be lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly "wrong", though it isn't common. Knex requires `.then` because it has to be able to tell when the query is done, as opposed to mid-build.

[Example from the docs](http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-Promises) (commentary added):

```
knex.select('name').from('users')    
  .where('id', '>', 20)              // Can I issue the query yet?
  .andWhere('id', '<', 200)          // Okay I'll...oh, you have more conditions.
  .limit(10)                         // Hey, I'm here, still ready...
  .offset(x)                         // Just let me know when you want me to--
  .then(function(rows) {             // OH OKAY I'll issue it now.
    return _.pluck(rows, 'name');
  })
```

Google's API.js helper [follows this pattern too](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises#batch-requests), specifically for immediate vs batched queries:

> When you create a request with the intention of adding it to a batch, do not invoke its `then` method until after the request has been added to the batch. If the `then` method is invoked before the request is added, the request is sent immediately instead of as part of the batch.

As [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) pointed out, this is not explicitly specified anywhere in the docs: In order for the object to be [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) compliant, it must have a method named `then` with the proper semantics and return value, and nothing specifies that `then` cannot have additional behavior. Naturally this prohibits these API libraries from renaming the `then` method to something more apt, like `thenIssueRequest` or `thenGetResponse`. (You can *add* an alias, but `then` is required to exist.)

As an API designer, the only alternative would be to separate the creation of the promise with the chaining of `then`, with the caveat that almost every call to `then` would have an extra method call that precedes or wraps it. Because `then` is the only way to access the result, I can understand how optimizing for the common case would result in removing the extra method.

```
fluentApi.createRequest().parameterA(1).parameterB(2).issue().then(...);
// or
fluentApi.issue(fluentApi.createRequest().parameterA(1).parameterB(2)).then(...);
```

---

Finally, bear in mind that you should always `catch` a Promise at some point, which would trigger the request:

```
knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
  table.string('name')
}).catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

...and that [both arguments to `then` are optional](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-23), so if you insist on skipping error handling you can even have an empty `then`:

```
knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
  table.string('name')
}).then(null);


knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
  table.string('name')
}).then();
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is wrong; calling `then()` should not have any side-effects beyond the promise itself (i.e., executing the callback).

However, the spec doesn't actually say anything about this.

Comment: I agree that it feels wrong for `then()` to have side-effects beyond calling the fulfillment callback, but is there any basis for this intuition?

Answer (score 1):

`knex` is a query builder. `then` is just a helper function that executes the generated [SQL] statements and calls the `then` function of a promise object behind the scenes. If you replace the `then` with the `.toString` function you will get the generated string. `then` here is not a method of a promise object.

From `knex` source code:

```
Target.prototype.then = function(/* onFulfilled, onRejected */) {
   const result = this.client.runner(this).run()
   return result.then.apply(result, arguments);
};
```

Comment: The schema builder does return a promise, according to the [Knex documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Schema). Also, the function in the code you quote _is_ returning a promise: `result` is the return value of `runner.run()`, which returns a Bluebird promise. See [this line from the source](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/runner.js#L27). Can you edit your answer?

Comment: @mheiber That's actually what I am trying to say. The `then` function itself is not a method of a promise object and _returns_ a promise object.

Comment: Then, that's just a horrible design choice by knex to offer a `.then()` method that isn't a promise handler.  Weird.  Misleading.  Should have been named something like `.exec()` to avoid this type of confusion.

Comment: @Vohuman, I see, thanks for explaining. So the Knex documentation is correct that the schema builder returns a promise, but, as you point out, Knex also executes a side effect before returning the promise. So my question about spec compliance is not relevant in this case. Very helpful.

Comment: @jfriend00 Well, I agree that it can be misleading but it makes the API more concise. For example you can code `Promise.all([ knex('table').truncate(), knex('another_table').insert({...}) ])` and the instances are coerced to promise objects.

Comment: @Vohuman - They either are or aren't promises.  If they are `thenables` and they follow the promise spec, then they're promises.  Someone else said they aren't promises and that only after call `.then()` do you get a promise.  It sure seems confusing.

Comment: What's particularly bad about this scheme is that attaching two `.then()` handlers (a perfectly legal thing to do with a real promise) looks like it will call `.run()` twice.  That is very un-promiselike.  In this case, `.then()` is really a proxy for `obj.client.runner(this).run().then()` and I'd argue it should not have been called `.then()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't think the `run` is called more than once in that case as the `then` method returns a promisified runner and then there is no query instance. I think there is also an `.exec` method for executing the queries.

Comment: ... But you are right that scheme can be confusing. I haven't checked the bluebird source code but I think `then` and other promise related methods that have been added to the APIs are used to make the APIs magically work with bluebird. Looks like the library follows the facade pattern which has it's own cons and pros. The authors of the library have made an ORM that uses the knex library and it has many, d'oh, awkward, terrible APIs. I have used it and it hurts your feelings.